# Percent case statements

Tags: c++, percentage

I was just writing an if statement to "spawn" objects in a map and I was playing with percents, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. This is what I have:

```
int chance = rng_.nextInt(0, 100);
if(chance <= 20) // 20%
{
    // Spawn a chest
}
else if((chance > 20) && (chance <= 50)) // 30%
{
    // Spawn a monster
}
// Otherwise don't spawn nothing
```

Is this a correct approach or I'm just wrong?

Edit: Ok, I have fixed the code and now I think the question is solved.

Comment: What do you want the probabilities to be?

Comment: Yes, I see now that I'm wrong. It would be this way: 20% -> spawn a chest, 30% -> spawn a monster and 50% -> don't spawn nothing. My mind just was blown up with the percentages I was giving in the prior code >.<U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming rng_.nextInt is generating a number between 0 and 100, and it is a linear distributions (any number between 0 and 99 is just as likely as any other number), then 0-19 would be a chest (20 percent chance), 20-49 would be a monster (30 percent chance), and anything between 50 and 99 (50 percent chance) would spawn nothing.  So the code would look like:

```
int chance = rng_.nextInt(0,100);
if ( chance < 20 ) 
{
  // spawn a chest
}
else if ( chance < 50 ) 
{
   // spawn a monster
}
else
{
  // Do other items if required.  
}
```

so 20+30+50 = 100 which equates to 0-99 (100 integer values) in your random number generation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 20 instead 30 in the first if? And yes, I'm using Mersenne twister for random generations.

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  It should be 20 not 30.  Bad typing... :(  Will edit it with the corrections.

Answer (score 3):

No, because

`30% + 70% + 30%`  is more than `100%`

in your code the chance of *"Spawn a monster"* is `40%` not `70%`

Comment: Yes! I noticed after @sftrabbit comment. Thank you!